# boost::spirit::qi rule reduce parsing error

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I try to parse a list of `integer` and `double` pairs using `boost::spirit::qi`. An `integer` precedes and follows to this list. An example of this list is:

```
20 1 1.3 2 2.3 30
```

The structure I want to create is:

```
typedef std::vector< std::pair<int, double> > vec_t;
struct list_s{
  int first;
  std::vector< std::pair<int, double> > list;
  int last;
};
```

Also I added error handling to my parser using `qi::on_error` and converting all sequences `>>` to expects `>`.

My implementation is:

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

typedef std::vector< std::pair<int, double> > vec_t;
struct list_s{
  int first;
  vec_t list;
  int last;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    list_s,
    (int, first)
    (vec_t, list)
    (int, last)
)

template <typename Iterator>
struct list_parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, list_s(), ascii::space_type >
{
  public:
    list_parser() : list_parser::base_type(r) {
      r = qi::eps >>
        (
          qi::int_
          > *( qi::int_ > qi::double_ )
          > qi::int_
        );

      r.name("r");
      qi::on_error<qi::fail>
        (
         r
         , std::cout
         << phoenix::val("\nError! Expecting ")
         << qi::labels::_4 
         << phoenix::val(" here: \"")
         << phoenix::construct<std::string>(qi::labels::_3, qi::labels::_2)
         << phoenix::val("\"\n\n")
        );
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, list_s(), ascii::space_type > r;
};

int main() {
  std::string str("20 1 1.3 2 2.3 30");

  list_s r;
  list_parser<std::string::const_iterator> p;
  std::string::const_iterator iter = str.begin();
  std::string::const_iterator end = str.end();
  if( qi::phrase_parse(iter, end, p, ascii::space, r) ){
    std::cout << r.first << std::endl;
    for(auto& i : r.list) std::cout << i.first << " , " << i.second << std::endl;
    std::cout << r.last << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When running this example I get

```
Error! Expecting <real> here: ""
```

I know I can change the list parsing rule to *sequence*

```
*( qi::int_ >> qi::double_ )
```

to overcome the above error. But then the parsing of `20 1 1.3 2 error 30` is also successful. The result would be:

```
20
1 , 1.3
2
```

Any suggestion to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expectation points create non-backtracking expectations.

So you cannot accept an alternative branch after it failed.

This means that your last int will be match by the int in `(int_ > double_)`. However that expression **requires** (`>`) that `double_` follows, and since it doesn't, it throws.

Replace by `>` there `>>`.

In fact, it looks like you just want to make sure that the whole input/line is consumed, so make your expectation *explicit*:

```
    r = (
            qi::int_
            > *( qi::int_ >> qi::double_ )
            > qi::int_
        )
        > qi::eoi
        ;
```

### Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6b2f231b5bd406c)</kbd>**

```
Note: also enabled rule debug (implicitly names the rule):

#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapted.hpp>

#include <iostream>

namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;
namespace qi      = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii   = boost::spirit::ascii;

typedef std::vector<std::pair<int, double>> vec_t;

struct list_s{
  int first;
  vec_t list;
  int last;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(list_s, first, list, last)

template <typename Iterator>
struct list_parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, list_s(), ascii::space_type>
{
  public:
    list_parser() : list_parser::base_type(r) {
        r = (
                qi::int_
                > *( qi::int_ >> qi::double_ )
                > qi::int_
            )
            > qi::eoi
            ;

      BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((r))

      qi::on_error<qi::fail>
        (
            r
            , std::cout
            << phoenix::val("\nError! Expecting ")
            << qi::labels::_4 
            << phoenix::val(" here: \"")
            << phoenix::construct<std::string>(qi::labels::_3, qi::labels::_2)
            << phoenix::val("\"\n\n")
        );
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, list_s(), ascii::space_type > r;
};

int main() {
    std::string str("20 1 1.3 2 2.3 30");

    using It = std::string::const_iterator;

    list_parser<It> p;
    It iter = str.begin(), end = str.end();

    list_s data;
    if (qi::phrase_parse(iter, end, p, ascii::space, data)){
        std::cout << data.first << "\n";

        for(auto& i : data.list) 
            std::cout << i.first << ", " << i.second << "\n";

        std::cout << data.last << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
20
1, 1.3
2, 2.3
30
```

And debug output:

```
<r>
    <try>20 1 1.3 2 2.3 30</try>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[[20, [[1, 1.3], [2, 2.3]], 30]]</attributes>
</r>
```

For error input:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/044f1b32720948c6)</kbd>**

```
Error! Expecting <eoi> here: "error 30"
```

With debug output:

```
<r>
  <try>20 1 1.3 2 error 30</try>
  <fail/>
</r>
```

Comment: The asker has tried that but does not like that it accepts input like `20 1 1.3 2 error 30` (for definitions of "accept").

Comment: It does when "accept" means the `parse` returns true. I think he/she needs either a separator or to use lookahead.

Comment: It doesn't. Read closely. (Clarified in the answer text)

Comment: I didn't catch the qi::eoi (that could be qi::eol if he/she needs several lines). Anyway he loses the error checking.

Comment: He doesn't. He has all the error checking that the ambiguous grammar allows for. (He might want to be more specific about how many pairs he expects, but OP didn't supply any information there).

Comment: [Another approach](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a36225ec3bce077) (uglier, probably worse performance, slightly better error messages imho).

Comment: @cv_and_he I personally do not find that better. I strongly expect that there is metadata/redundancy in the other fields that should make it possible to tell up front how many pairs to expect ([e.g. like so](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cebf937023051fc9)), otherwise the distinction error _clearly_ not better, it's just differently biased. Otherwise the grammar should be "fixed" to remove the confusion (e.g. `"2 (1 1.3) (2 1.4) 42"`, problems solved)

Comment: Thanks both sehe and @cv_and_he. Both examples are very helpful. I was expecting a rule with better error messaging. When I posted the question, I was thinking that I might be able to use `on_error<retry>`

Comment: How? Why? Retrying won't change the rules nor the input. You could make a conditional `eps` somewhere based on business logic to decide what branch to take/message to generate